# Read unknown number of ints separated by spaces or ends of lines

Tags: python-3.x, input

I am trying to find a way to get this right, I found some bits that answer this question only partially, such as:

```py
from sys import stdin 
lines = stdin.read().splitlines()
```

but this would only take in ints separated by lines

```py
inp = list(map(int,input().split()))
```

while this only reads ints separated by spaces

I am stuck on this and couldn't figure out an intersection for the two. I am trying to learn EOF function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys

numbers = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    numbers += [int(number) for number in line.split()]
print(numbers)
```

Keep in mind that you have to explicitly send EOF on the terminal for the loop to finish (ctrl+d in bash). Otherwise, it will be stuck in for loop forever.

Comment: When does print function realize? I am using VSC and just realized if I hit enter I just input a new number, so I am not sure how to do this

Comment: CTRL+d on *nix and CTRL+z on windows